# "Justify-content : space around" doesn't apply on a line although it should

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cabinet d'avocats à Paris 8</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300&display=swap");
    </style>

    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img
          src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/Logo-JDB.png.webp"
          alt="logo"
          height="123px"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="ul">
        <ul class="list-1">
          <li>
            <img
              src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/enveloppe-icon.png"
              alt="enveloppe-logo"
              height="16px"
            />
          </li>
          <li>contact@jdbavocats.com</li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>
            <img
              src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/phone-icon.png"
              alt="phone icon"
              height="16px"
            />
          </li>
          <li>+33 1 42 56 96 96</li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>
            <img
              src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/window-icon.png"
              alt="window icon"
              height="16px"
            />
          </li>
          <li>Devis gratuit</li>
          <li>|</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="list-2">
          <li>ACCUEIL</li>
          <li>COMPÉTENCES</li>
          <li>EQUIPE</li>
          <li>PRESTATIONS</li>
          <li>PUBLICATIONS</li>
          <li>CONTACT</li>
          <li>
            <img
              src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/Magnifying-glass-icon.png"
              alt="Magnifying glass icon"
              height="16px"
            />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.list-1,
.list-2 {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
}
```

To practice I'm reproducing this web site : https://www.jdbavocats.com/

Here is where I'm at : [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE5qi.png)

The problem is here :

```
.list-1,
.list-2 {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
```

It gives a very strange result because the first line is spaced but in the other one the words are still glued together, I made a visual illustration (my comments are in red) :

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IewQo.png)

I don't understand why the effect of space-around doesn't apply to the second line ?

I'm expecting the line to be spaced-around then I can do margins and re-arrange the words as it is on the original website to match the dispositions.

Thank you

Comment: Weird. I reproduced your scenario with the code you provided and it works fine here. Maybe something else that you did not mention here is messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not enough horizontal space, your `li` items are simply pushed together, leaving no space between them. To avoid that, add some left and/or right `padding`, which will always keep a *minimum* distance between the `li` elements:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.list-1,
.list-2 {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
}
.list-2 li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.list-2 li:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.list-2 li:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<style>
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300&display=swap");
</style>

<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/Logo-JDB.png.webp" alt="logo" height="123px" />
  </div>
  <div class="ul">
    <ul class="list-1">
      <li>
        <img src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/enveloppe-icon.png" alt="enveloppe-logo" height="16px" />
      </li>
      <li>contact@jdbavocats.com</li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li>
        <img src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/phone-icon.png" alt="phone icon" height="16px" />
      </li>
      <li>+33 1 42 56 96 96</li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li>
        <img src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/window-icon.png" alt="window icon" height="16px" />
      </li>
      <li>Devis gratuit</li>
      <li>|</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-2">
      <li>ACCUEIL</li>
      <li>COMPÉTENCES</li>
      <li>EQUIPE</li>
      <li>PRESTATIONS</li>
      <li>PUBLICATIONS</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li>
        <img src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/Site-avocats/Assets/Imgs/Magnifying-glass-icon.png" alt="Magnifying glass icon" height="16px" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```